# Increment operation mechanism

Tags: java, variable-assignment, atomic

As many developers know, increment operator isn't atomic.

For instance:

```
public void incrementId(){ // id being an int field
   id++;
}
```

Actually, this corresponds to three distinct operations:

```
int temp = id;
id = id + 1;  
id = temp;
```

Besides, this method behaves similarly:

```
    public void incrementId(){ // id being an int field
       id = id + 1;  // three steps also here
    }
```

My question is:

What is the real difference behind the scene between following both operations:

```
id = id + 1; //three steps => non atomic

id = anotherIntVariable + 1; // one step => atomic
```

What concept forces the compiler to translate the first one into 3 steps and not the other?

Comment: Your three-line example results in no change to `id`.

Comment: The 2nd is also not atomic, unless of course both `id` and `anotherIntVariable` are on registers - but you cannot assume it. It will also be translated to a several machine instructions

Comment: Sorry, I've not well written it. Updated

Comment: I still think your 3-liner is wrong

Comment: What would be the three lines? In fact, my question is focus on that under the hood... I don't figure out why 3 lines...I find the temp variable redundant.

Comment: the whole operation of read-modify-write has to atomic. It shouldn't matter which variables are being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What concept forces the compiler to translate the first one into 3
>   steps and not the other?

it is not, `id = xyz + 1` will be compiled to the following byte code:

```
 7  iload_2 [xyz]
 8  iconst_1
 9  iadd
10  istore_1 [id]
```

It is easy to see from the byte code that the above is not "one step"

Comment: So, actually there are not 3 steps but 4 steps even for id++, right?

Comment: @Mik378: Not exactly, at machine level there could be even more (or less), depending on many things - including the specific architecture of the machine and the JVM implementation.

Comment: At the machine level this is very likely to be a one-op `inc`.

Comment: @amit So, if I figure out the whole, it would be wrong to think that a simple assignment like `id = anotherId` is not atomic. Indeed, we might think that byte code potentially convert it to:                `7 iload_2 [anotherId]                                                  8 istore_1 [id]`  meaning two steps... That seems stupid, I agree, but I imagine that it simply does a variable storage since processor does not need to eval `anotherId`to process some kind of basic operations on it (like additions)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Depends on the architecture and the number of available registers, it might be needed to be first loaded from memory and later stored..

Comment: Well, the predominant architecture, x86, has always supported `inc`ing a memory location directly.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing saying that this:

```
id = anotherVariable + 1
```

Will not be performed in 3 steps. But no matter how many times you run the code above, the end result will always be the same (the value of the variable `id` will always be whatever was on `anotherIntVariable` plus 1), as in the example `id = id + 1`, the previously set value on the `id` variable drives the new `id` value, and the end value of `id` might not be what you are expecting if you experience race conditions.

A few notes:

- If you are setting the `id` variable from multiple threads, no matter how you are setting it, you need to synchronize it. Always, or else the value might not be set at all (see chapter 3 of Java Concurrency in Practice). Alternatively, you can make the `id` variable volatile;
- This only matters if `id` can actually be accessed from multiple threads. If that is not the case (for example, if `id` is a local variable in a method), then you don't need to worry about locking/ etc... This holds true even if you have anonymous threads in a method, as they can only access local variables that are declared final.